# Facebook SDK return URL

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

i use the following php script:

```
<?php

//facebook application configuration

$fbconfig['appid' ] = "****";

$fbconfig['secret'] = "****";

try{

    include_once ('facebook/src/facebook.php');

}

catch(Exception $o){

    print_r($o);

}

$facebook = new Facebook(array(

  'appId'  => $fbconfig['appid'],

  'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'],

  'cookie' => true,

));



$user       = $facebook->getUser();

$loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(

        array(

            'scope'         => 'publish_stream'

        )

);

if ($user) {

  try {

    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');

    $user_friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');

    $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {

   // d($e);

    $user = null;

  }

}

if (!$user) {

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";

    exit;
}



 $args = array(

'message'   => 'Blabla',

'link'      => 'http://www.Blabla.nl/',

'caption'   => 'Blabla'

);
$post_id = $facebook->api("/me/feed", "post", $args);

header('Location: '.$domein.'/direct-inloggen/melding/accountAangemaakt/');
?>
```

It's the Facebook SDK script.
It works fine, but i have two questions about it:

- When the script runs, and people accept the facebook question, the script posts a message on the wall.
  But then they return to the page they came from. I wan't to use another return url, how can i set this up?
- When people once declined the facebook acceptants question, they get a blank page when the script runs, untill they clear all sessions and cookies. What can i do about this?

Comment: Use an `else` statement. - *"When people once declined the facebook acceptants question, they get a blank page when the script run"*

Comment: Hi Fred, but how do i know if they declined the acceptants?

Comment: That I couldn't say for sure on how to set it up, am not much into FB apps myself. However, since it's mostly DB-based stuff, and this I know as standard SQL, is that once you get the user's ID, then you could set up a table just for that, and log it from there; theoretically.

Answer (score 0):

Found out how to setup a redirect url.
I had to change the function getLoginUrl in base_facebook.php, wich is the baseurl as default in the SDK script.

Now i only want to know how to check if someone already declined and how to reset.